# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - file from the same directory

Tags: python

For some reason when I do the following:

```
filename = 'time_series_covid_confirmed_US.csv'
with open (os.path.join("mnt/c", "Users/ibhat/repo/nasa-hackathon-2020/covid-parsing", filename)) as csv_file:
```

I get "No such file or directory" when trying to access a csv file. Any ideas?

Comment: yes. did you print the output string that `os.path.join` generate?! maybe you generate a wrong path by mistake
`mnt/c/Users/ibhat/repo/nasa-hackathon-2020/covid-parsing/time_series_covid_confirmed_US.csv` this is the output string. is it valid path?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by print it out? do you mean print(os.path.join("path", "to", filename))?

Comment: please take the output string=> `mnt/c/Users/ibhat/repo/nasa-hackathon-2020/covid-parsing/time_series_covid_confirmed_US.csv`,
and try to open it in terminal vim or gedit.

Comment: @IshaBhatt I hope the forward slash helped, if so please consider marking my answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a forward slash before `mnt`:

```
filename = 'time_series_covid_confirmed_US.csv'
with open (os.path.join("/mnt/c", "Users/ibhat/repo/nasa-hackathon-2020/covid-parsing", filename)) as csv_file:
```